# How to assign variable to styles elements in Material-UI from a .ini file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have to take a variable color from a .ini file and assign it as the background color to my app. I am completely confused on how to accomplish this. I get the color in login page from the .ini file but then I don't know how to assign it to the styles object in my main component which exists outside of the class.

I have tried using import/export and promises but I believe I am not doing it right. I don't know whether to make the api call to get the color in my main component where the styles object is or make the call from my login page where I am using it to get other information as well.

Main Component

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    minHeight: '100vh',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appContent: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  mainContent: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: '48px 36px 48px', //exists outside of main component
    background: '#eaeff1' // this is where I want to put the variable
  },
};
```

App.js //Top level component one down from Root.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("IN THE APP", window)
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/changePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/signin" />
        <Route path="/" component={AsyncApp} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

Login page // where I am making the api call to get the information

```
  async componentDidMount(){

    let response1 = await fetch('/api/getStatus2').then(res => res.json())

      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", response1)

      this.setState({
        display_name: response1.display_name
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom style properties that you need to load dynamically can be placed in your theme.

At the top-level, you need some state for holding the variables that your API should load. This is called `themeVariables` in my example. The setter is then passed to the component (`Fetcher` in my example) that simulates the API call. You could put this setter into context if you have many layers in between and don't want to pass it explicitly as a prop through all the layers.

I'm initializing `themeVariables` with default values so that its intended structure is clear and so that styling that uses the custom variables will still work before the API call occurs. Whenever `themeVariables` changes, it is used to create a new theme which is provided to the entire App.

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import MainContent from "./MainContent";
import Fetcher from "./Fetcher";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const defaultThemeVariables = {
  palette: {
    mainContentBackgroundColor: "lightblue"
  }
};
function App() {
  const [themeVariables, setThemeVariables] = React.useState(
    defaultThemeVariables
  );
  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createMuiTheme(themeVariables), [
    themeVariables
  ]);
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <MainContent />
        <Fetcher setThemeVariables={setThemeVariables} />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Once the API call completes, it needs to use the setter passed to it to set `themeVariables` appropriately.

`Fetcher.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Fetcher = ({ setThemeVariables }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // This is simulating handling the results of an API call to get the color.
    setThemeVariables({
      palette: {
        mainContentBackgroundColor: "lightgreen"
      }
    });
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Trigger Fetch</button>;
};
export default Fetcher;
```

After triggering the fetch, you will see the background color of the main content change accordingly.

`MainContent.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  mainContent: {
    background: theme.palette.mainContentBackgroundColor
  }
}));
const MainContent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <div className={classes.mainContent}>Main Content</div>;
};
export default MainContent;
```

[image: Edit API-loaded variables in theme]